# svn update command failed after password is changed, why the same user (jenkins) is used, but different username&password will be found?

Tags: python, svn, jenkins

My team use Jenkins to generate iOS builds with python script, and the `subprocess.Popen()` is used to run shell command. My SVN password is changed yesterday, and I have updated it in both Jenkins's Credentials & auth folder under jenkins user's ~/.subversion folder.

However, `svn update` has different results between terminal and Jekins.

In terminal, everything works fine, if I login to jenkins user by

```
sudo su jenkins
```

then:

```
bash-3.2$ whoami
jenkins
bash-3.2$ svn update ../../skins/MyApp/skin.bundle
Updating

'/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/MyAppSpace/skins/MyApp/skin.bundle':
Restored        
'/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/MyAppSpace/skins/MyApp/skin.bundle'
Restored     
'/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/MyAppSpace/skins/MyApp/skin.bundle/Resources'
Restored
'/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/MyAppSpace/skins/MyApp/skin.bundle/Resources/Images'
Restored     
'/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/MyAppSpace/skins/MyApp/skin.bundle/text_templates.json'
At revision 82894.
```

However, in Jenkins I run the script with `subprocess.Popen( "svn update ..", shell=True,..,..)`, I will get error:

```
whoami
jenkins

svn update "../../skins/MyApp/skin.bundle"
Updating '/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/MyAppSpace/skins/MyApp/skin.bundle':

svn: E215004: Authentication failed and interactive prompting is disabled; see the --force-interactive option
svn: E215004: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://My_SVN_URL/skins/MyApp'
svn: E215004: No more credentials or we tried too many times.
Authentication failed
```

I know the problem could be corrected by add --username & --password parameters with svn update command, while I do not want to modify my script but did some system environment settings. I am more curious about the different behaviour between terminal and Jenkins, why the same user triggers the `svn update` command, but different username & password set will be used?

### Edit

`svn info` command works for both terminal and Jenkins script.